# Angular: $http change method on adding data with post

Tags: angularjs

I am using fuse template and accessing my web service by using `$http`, its working fine if i am using `method: 'POST'` without send any data but whenever i am adding some data with post like: `data: {text:'test'}` and send request to my web service its change the method type `POST` to `OPTIONS`.

My Code:

```
$scope.submit = function(){

   $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://www.example.com/api-link',
      data: {test: 'hello'},
      header: {

            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
   }).then(function(result){

          console.log(result);
   });
}
```

When i am checking in browser network its showing method type `OPTIONS`. Can anyone please tell what is wrong in my code?

Thanks

Comment: which is the service you are consuming?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code; OPTIONS are `preflight` requests made when you perform a "cross domain" (CORS) request. Soon after the "OPTIONS" request you should be able to see the "POST" request as well provided your "OPTIONS" was success. Please have a look here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Custom API in Laravel 5.3